# General method for determining binary function

Tags: functions, problem-solving, binary

What is a general method for determining the simplest function $f(x,y)=z$ for a given set of values of $x$, $y$, and $z$. Simplicity being the fewest number of operations required in the function, notwithstanding other definitions of functional simplicity.

For example, given the binary values in the table below:

```
|  x   |  y   |  z   |
|------|------|------|
| 0000 | 0000 | 1101 |
| 0000 | 0001 | 1111 |
| 0001 | 0000 | 1110 |
| 0010 | 0000 | 1011 |
| 0100 | 0000 | 0001 |
| 0101 | 0001 | 0000 |
| 0101 | 0010 | 0110 |
| 1000 | 0000 | 0101 |
| 1000 | 0001 | 0111 |
| 1000 | 0010 | 0001 |
| 1101 | 0001 | 1000 |
| 1101 | 0010 | 1110 |
```

This function can be determined to be a solution: $f(x, y) = ( x ~XOR~ ( x << 1 ) ~XOR~ ( y << 1 )) ~AND~ F_{16}$

In one of the comments here, a function solver was suggested. While this seems like a good approach, and can generate a solution, the extensive polynomial function found by a solver is not as simple as the solution identified above.

When using base 2, as in this example, operations like mask, shift, rotation, parity, or other binary functions can be used to generate a simpler solution.

My trial-and-error method, started with collecting data at the 0's for each variable. Then I tried various function combinations on the input variables to get an intermediate value, then tried operations on that intermediate value against the known solution for the input variables. Also, a lot of staring at the numbers was involved. I think there must be a more general method, possibly involving truth tables of each bit combination, then mapping the truth table patterns to known functions. Perhaps image or pattern recognition of the resulting truth tables could be used to composite a solution.

So, the question again is, can we describe a process or method to consistently recover simple functions used to generate outputs given their inputs?

Comment: Surely in general there are very many functions which could give those outputs for those inputs? Are there any restrictions on the kinds of functions you're looking for?

Comment: @79037662 i think minimizing the complexity of the function would be a constraint. If it could be solved with a shift and an xor, that would be preferable to a large constant bit mapping function.

Comment: Converting from binary to base 10 numbers, you could then use any "function generator" like Lagrange Polynomial interpolation or Newton's method

Comment: @HenryLee Good idea, I'll try  that.  I'm interested to see if the simplicity of the original function flows through, or if we lose concepts like xor, parity, etc.